# Difference between property and class instance swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift programming, and i have a question as follows:
I have a class named Weather

```
class Weather {

}
```

then i define 2 things:

```
var currentWeather1 = Weather()

var currentWeather2: Weather!
```

Are they different syntax or the same meaning? What are they actually created in memory with these 2 statements?

Comment: The first one instantiates and creates it in the memory. The second one creates an empty pointer.

Comment: @ShamasS exactly..when compiling currentWeather2 = Weather() at the time only it allocates memory.

Answer (score 4):

```
var currentWeather1 = Weather()
```

This declares a variable of type Weather and assigns a new instance of Weather to it. The syntax `Weather()` creates an instance and runs its initialiser. The compiler infers the type of `currentWeather1` to be `Weather`. The statement above is exactly equivalent to

```
var currentWeather1: Weather = Weather()
```

The other statement:

```
var currentWeather2: Weather!
```

declares an implicit optional variable. This variable is of optional type i.e. it's type is `Optional<Weather>`. This means that it needs to be unwrapped if you want to get at the value. However, the `!` means that the compiler will put in the unwrapping code for you. A normal optional would look like this:

```
var currentWeather3: Weather?
```

but when you need to use it, you have to unwrap it e.g.

```
if let foo = currentWeather3 
{
    // foo is the unwrapped weather
}
let string = currentWeather3?.description // string is an optional String 
let string2 = currentWeather3!.description // string2 is a String
```

The last example with the `!` is a forced unwrapping. If `currentWeather3` is nil, when the line executes, the program will crash. The declaration of `currentWeather2` means the compiler treats every mention of `currentWeather2` as if it has an implicit `!` after it.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is

```
var currentWeather2: Weather!
```

Declares a variable by creating a references of the `Weather` in system table. But does not allocate any memory for the variable

```
var currentWeather1 = Weather()
```

`Weather` object is created by allocating memory and the location of the variable is assigned to the system table entry of age.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentWeather2: Weather!
```

The above statement does not allocate memory for an instance of Weather, it only allocates a stack variable currentWeather2. The reference pointers only are allocated on stack. The time it hits the `currentWeather2 = Weather()`, it allocates on "heap".

To access class properties & methods refer directly from the class name rather than with an instance of the class.

it will be helpful to understand more,it's in C# but concept is same
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types